# Avoid cycle between java packages SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I am getting from sonar the following major bug:
Remove the dependency on the source file "src/main/java/com/credorax/brain/model/context/Credential.java" to break a package cycle

Which actually means if i remove the import, it will break the cycle.
I don't understand what they expect me to do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

A package cycle is created when a class in package A uses a class in package B, and a class in package B (it may or not be the same class) uses a class in package A (again, maybe the same class, maybe not). This is thought to indicate poor design, and so it's advised against.

Typically, you break package cycles by reconsidering your package design. Maybe A and B should really be one package. Or maybe one of the classes in package A ought to be moved to package B. Or vice versa. But the idea here is that if you drew a diagram of which packages use each other, it would not look like spaghetti.